# Layout margin and padding values

Tags: android, android-layout, view

I am designing an android app for normal screens with all densities like mdpi,hdpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi. I am using layout top margin and layout left margin attributes for specifying the widgets positions in linear layout and relative layout.I have taken mdpi as a base density and considering screen sizes like 320X480(mdpi), 480X800(hdpi), 640X960(xhdpi), 960X1440(xxhdpi). I am specifying the values in dp. But, the positions of widgets looks different in different density mobiles like, in xhdpi it looks different when compared to mdpi.  I am using the background images(from photoshop) relative to 320X480 pixel, 480X800 pixel, 640X960 pixel, 960X1440 pixel.

Am I doing in the right way or Do I need to change my design approach?

Comment: try to use dpi insted of dp...

Comment: dp=dip from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension